# Text file to dict in python?

Tags: python

I have a text file which is consisted of this:

```
Alice;Lodging;49.99;10/12/2016
Bob;Dining;8.42;10/13/2016
Charles;Lodging;55.76;10/14/2016
David;Dining;19.95;10/15/2016
Eve;Rental;105.99;10/16/2016
Frank;Rental;raft;10/17/2016
```

How can I store this in a dict that has the service as the key and the amount total as the value? I'm just starting learning Python and I'm so confused lol.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) here:

```
from collections import defaultdict

with open('file') as f: # open file in read only mode
    my_dict = defaultdict(float)  # will hold default value as 0.0 for any key
    for line in f.readlines():  # iterate over each line
        _, key, val, _ = line.split(';') # split line on ';' and take 1 & 2 index
        my_dict[key] += val  # add amount to service
```